# Elastic search Word delimeter

Tags: elasticsearch

I got an elastic search engine in my project. I need to find an identifier with it. The problem is that this identifier got '-' inside. Elastic search makes a split with this character, searching by two strings instead one. For example:

Identifier: 023-019125
Elastic search split it and search by 023 and 019125, that's returns me many result that I don't want.

How can I make elastic search use an exact search only for this field. Here is my actual elastic search config:

```
Indexes:
    service:
        properties:
            identifier:
                type: text
```

In type field i tried keyword, text, regex

Comment: If the "keyword" data type is not working for you, you can try using the "keyword" analyzer instead to check whether it solves your problem.

Comment: Can I apply it only to this field?